# Using Google Apps Script to get files in large folder,next page token issue?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have large google drive folders with about 2900 files, i want to split them into many subfolders,each folder has 100 files
but when i run my script ,there is only one folder created and about 90 files added to that folder it seems that the script stop here (no files added anymore)

i searched and found a thing "pagetoken" ,it says that i have to loop through next pagetoken to bypass the limit file per page,
How to loop through pagetoken to get all files in folder, or any method to loop through 2900 files ,please ?
 here is my code :

```
    function SplitFolder(source,target) {

  var files = source.getFiles();
  var i = 0; // count of files, to limit 100 files per folder
  var n = 1; // name of folder = folder count
  var folderidz; // id of folder
  var foldercopied; // target folder to copy
  // create first folder
  folderidz = target.createFolder(n).getId(); // create folder name "1"
  foldercopied = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderidz); // get folder id
    while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    i++;
    if (i == 100) // if > 100 files ,create new folder
    {
      n++; // number of folder
      i = 0; //reset file count of new folder
      folderidz = target.createFolder(n).getId(); // get id of new created folder
      foldercopied = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderidz); //get folder 
    }
    foldercopied.addFile(file); // copy files to that folder
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the the limit file per page is for the [Advanced Drive API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive), and in your case (using the DriveApp class) the iteration might end because you have exceeded the [Script Run Time](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations) (Current limitations).

I might be wrong about the latter though, but the continueFileIterator should work anyway. As the documentation states for the DriveApp.continueFileIterator :

> Resumes a file iteration using a continuation token from a previous iterator. This method is useful if processing an iterator in one execution would exceed the maximum execution time. Continuation tokens are generally valid for one week.

Here is the idea how it works:

```
function getFilesInFolder( folderid )
{  
// Get the token from the last search
var token = PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty('iteratorToken');

// If this is the first time you iterate or you have finished the list
//before, the token is null
var files = (token == null) ? DriveApp.getFolderById(folderid).getFiles() : 
DriveApp.continueFileIterator(token);

if( files.hasNext() )
{
// Move to next file 
var file = files.next();

// Save the token
 PropertiesService.getUserProperties()
                  .setProperty('iteratorToken', files.getContinuationToken() );

// Should return a new name everytime
throw file.getName();
}
else{ 
// If there was no next file, we have finished iteration and can clear the token
PropertiesService.getUserProperties().deleteProperty('iteratorToken');
 }
}
```

Oh and sorry, I cannot seem to make the code section pretty. Anyways, worked for me, so you should get the idea.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, i really appreacite it ! I will try it